# Which word is searched for more in the world, and locally?

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search

I have two words:

- fishing
- fish

I want to know:

1. which word is searched for more in the world,
2. more in Africa
3. more in south africa
4. more in Namibia

How do you check this?

The search engine I am interested in is Google, but if more search engines can easily be checked, that would be great too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google's Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__c=1000000000&__u=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS) can provide everything you are looking for. You can search for exact words, similar words, and many other specific criteria and filter by country and many other settings as well. You will get results like this:

[image]

Keep in mind, however, that while these numbers are provided by Google, their [accuracy](http://www.seochat.com/c/a/google-optimization-help/is-googles-keyword-tool-accurate-analysis-using-actual-data/) is [questionable](http://moz.com/blog/be-careful-using-adwords-for-keyword-research).